# Open Drawer component from Toolbar component in React

Tags: reactjs, drawer

I have written a Nav component which renders react-md Drawer component. Two functions in this file control Drawer's visibility-

```
showDrawer = () => {
    this.setState({ visible: true });
};

hideDrawer = () => {
    this.setState({ visible: false });
};
```

This component is rendered at App level.

I have a page with Toolbar component. This toolbar has a menu button that should open the Drawer in Nav component.

```
class Catalog extends React.Component {
 render() { 
    return (
        <div>
        <Toolbar themed fixed title="Catalog" nav={<Button icon onClick={this.showDrawer}>menu</Button>} />
....
```

How can I implement it in React?

Comment: The toolbar component is part of another Route?? or is it a direct child component of App? How are you managing the application state? Are you using Redux?

Answer (score 1):

You're close. Assuming we're just using plain-old React, you'll want to call the constructor function (which requires calling super as well), bind the 'this' context to the functions, define those functions and call them in the toolbar code you have below.

Assuming we're not involving Redux and using component state, you'll also want to set an initial state for your app (going with false for my example).

When I do this myself, I'll usually condense the functions into one 'toggle' function which you can do nicely with a ternary, checking the state to decide whether to open or close the nav.

Not sure if that fully answers your question, but hopefully it's a start.

All together, that looks something like this. (Note that the current implementation will only open the drawer and not close it):

```
 export default class Catalog extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.hideDrawer = this.hideDrawer.bind(this);
    this.showDrawer = this.showDrawer.bind(this);
    this.getNavStyle = this.getNavStyle.bind(this);

    this.state = { visible: false }
  }

  getNavStyle() {
    return this.state.visible
      ? {
        overflow: 'scroll',
        width: '200px',
      }
      : {
        overflow: 'visible',
        letterSpacing: '2px',
        width: '200px',
      };
    }
  showDrawer = () => {
    this.setState({ visible: true });
  };

  hideDrawer = () => {
      this.setState({ visible: false });
  };

  render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <Toolbar themed fixed title="Catalog"
            nav={
              <Button icon onClick={this.showDrawer}>
                menu
              </Button>}
             />
          </div>
        )
      }
    }
```

Comment: Setting visible property in Toolbar will not affect Drawer component's visibility.

Comment: Thanks - forgot to include this bit in which you correlate the component's open or closed state to a certain style. I've added that above.